# Sorting XML file by a subtag?

Tags: xml, sorting

I'm not a programmer (anymore).
I'm working with my windows media center PC, and trying to cut down the garbage in the mcechannelinfo.xml.

Easy enough to remove the other providers (cable carriers that I don't use), but now I'm in my provider trying to sort/remove the channels I don't get.

The data is sorted like this:

```
    <channel>
      <id>Atlanta, DISH Atlanta::ZBUSN::mcepg</id>
      <name>ZBUSN</name>
      <num>708</num>
      <subnum>0</subnum>
    </channel>
    <channel>
      <id>Atlanta, DISH Atlanta::KIDTV::mcepg</id>
      <name>KIDTV</name>
      <num>9394</num>
      <subnum>0</subnum>
    </channel>
    <channel>
      <id>Atlanta, DISH Atlanta::WSBK::mcepg</id>
      <name>WSBK</name>
      <num>8775</num>
      <subnum>0</subnum>
    </channel>
    <channel>
      <id>Atlanta, DISH Atlanta::BLOCK::mcepg</id>
      <name>BLOCK</name>
      <num>349</num>
      <subnum>0</subnum>
    </channel>
```

As you can see, that's a mess.  It's neither alphabetical by channel name, nor numerical by number!!

How can I sort the data by name or even better, by number?
I have access to few tools - Excel, notepad++, and another program I grabbed called XMLMIND...

Please help!

Ok. I tried your response and it didn't seem to work, so I'm pasting a bigger clip from the top of the XML so you can see everything.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Channels> 
 <category name="Atlanta, DISH Atlanta">
    <channel>
      <id>Atlanta, DISH Atlanta::ESPNA::mcepg</id>
      <name>ESPNA</name>
      <num>148</num>
      <subnum>0</subnum>
    </channel>
    <channel>
      <id>Atlanta, DISH Atlanta::FSP::mcepg</id>
      <name>FSP</name>
      <num>391</num>
      <subnum>0</subnum>
    </channel>
    <channel>
      <id>Atlanta, DISH Atlanta::ACMAX::mcepg</id>
      <name>ACMAX</name>
      <num>313</num>
      <subnum>0</subnum>
    </channel>
    <channel>
      <id>Atlanta, DISH Atlanta::TBSHD::mcepg</id>
      <name>TBSHD</name>
      <num>139</num>
      <subnum>0</subnum>
    </channel>
```

Your assistance is greatly appreciated, in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a XSLT 1.0 stylesheet. It's not hard to find a parser, and you can even use an online service to process it.

You didn't post a well-formed XML, so I will assume you have a parent node above `<channel>` which I will call `<channels>`. So I'm assuming your file is something like this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="order-channels.xsl"?>
<channels>
      <channel>
        <id>Atlanta, DISH Atlanta::ZBUSN::mcepg</id>
        <name>ZBUSN</name>
        <num>708</num>
        <subnum>0</subnum>
      </channel>
  ...
</channels>
```

Create a file containing this XSL stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="channels">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="channel">
                <xsl:sort select="num"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now you can use a XSLT processor or service and transform your XML using the stylesheet. The resulting XML will have the `channel` nodes ordered by number.

You can also try it out using [this service](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html). Just copy the source XML into the XML textbox, and the XSL into the XSL box and press "Transform XML".

You can order by different criteria, replacing the `select` attribute in `<xsl:sort />` with some other field in the context of `channel`.

(Don't forget that I made assumptions about your XML source; you might have to adapt it to your source XML if what you posted is just a simplification).